# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs while upgrade on cleanup

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I was upgrading my laptop to Ubuntu 18.04 and it hanged on cleanup. I have no idea what to do next. Is there any right action to do?

Current state: [Upgrade log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIjW4.png)

Comment: All looks fine, be patient.

Comment: Killed process by xkill and restarted PC. Cleaned old kernels by apt autoremove. No problems faced for now.